# how to load multiple model in same controller codigniter

Tags: codeigniter

how to load multiple model in codigniter

class c_home extends CI_Controller {

```
         function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();

           $this->load->model('mhome/m_home');
           $this->load->model('mcommon/m_common');

         }
```

i have two model m_home and m_common
m_home load but m_common not loaded give Error 
Message: Undefined property: c_home::$m_common

Comment: Not clear about your question but this might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902966/load-multiple-models-in-array-codeigniter-framework

Comment: i have two model m_home and m_common
m_home load but m_common not loaded give Error 
Message: Undefined property: c_home::$m_common

Comment: Can you post c_home? The error is not in the loading of your model, but in the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the model correctly extends the CI_Model for m_common

example:

```
 class M_common extends CI_Model{    

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way for load multiple model :

```
function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model(array('mhome/m_home','mcommon/m_common'));

}
```