# Is it allowed to load multiple models in single Controller in CI3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Is it allowed to load multiple models in single Controller ? And my each model is loading same database in their controller. Thanks

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database() or die("Cannot open database");
        $this->load->model("Admin/Product_model");
        $this->load->model("Admin/Category_model");
        $this->load->model("Admin/Attribute_model");
        $this->load->model("Admin/Attribute_value_model");

    }
```

This is my controler constuctor. And in constuctors of all models I am loading same database. Like these,...

```
Class Attribute_value_model extends CI_Model
{ 
    Name : function __construct
    Returns : NULL
    Use : This is the constructor of project, loads the database on every times page is called

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database("default") or die("Cannot open");
    }
```

Comment: u can, getting errors?? just suggestion, use in array: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902966/load-multiple-models-in-array-codeigniter-framework`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load multiple models in a single controller.You can tell the model loading method to auto-connect by passing TRUE (boolean) via the third parameter, and connectivity settings, as defined in your database config file.
for example:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

//session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user', 'guru', TRUE);
        $this->load->model('student', 'santosh', TRUE);
    }

    function index() {
        //echo  $this->session->userdata('validuser'); 
        //   die('here');
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

            $pankaj = $this->guru->userinfo(1);
            var_dump($pankaj);
            $santosh = $this->santosh->studentinfo(1);
            var_dump($santosh);
            $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
        } else {
            //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        session_destroy();
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }

}
```

Comment: No not running yet.

Comment: If I use the same structure and if in each of these models, I am loading same database in all these models, it's not running

Answer (score 0):

### Issue resolved

1. Insted of loading database from each model, I directly loadaed
   default database from autoload.php.
2. So it prevents loading same
   database again

   //In autoload.php

   $autoload['libraries'] = array('mailchimp','session','form_validation','database');